# Tread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, exc-bad-access

I'm really new to programming and been working on an iPhone game by combining code from many different tutorials.

I added the `score` and `highScore` in my Gameplay scene and I wanted to display the `highScore` in the mainMenu scene.

The app runs for a while but sometimes when I go back to the mainmenu scene the app crashes:

> ( Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)

[Screenshot of the crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aYWV.png)

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

var playicon:SKSpriteNode!
var logo:SKSpriteNode!

var settingicon = SKSpriteNode()
var infoicon = SKSpriteNode()
var facebookbtn = SKSpriteNode()
var highScoreLbl = SKLabelNode()
var highScore = Int()
var highscorebg = SKSpriteNode()


var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class MainMenu: SKScene {         

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

 let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("highscore") != nil) {
        highScore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("highscore") as! NSInteger
       highScoreLbl.text = "\(highScore)"
    }

    highScoreLbl.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 + 80, y: self.frame.height / 2 - 20)
    highScoreLbl.zPosition = 4
    highScoreLbl.setScale(0)
    highScoreLbl.fontName = "Skater Girls Rock"
    highScoreLbl.fontSize = 100

    self.addChild(highScoreLbl)
    highScoreLbl.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 0.3))
}

}
```

Comment: Looks like `highScoreLbl` might be nil. Can you post the code where it is defined?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I updated the post to show how I defined the highScoreLbl.

Comment: Still not working :(